# Response from Cloudfront from S3 Origin keeps changing CORS Headers

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

here is my problem :
CORS are set as supposed to be on the S3 :

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

when I try to fetch a file (using jQuery with option CrossDomain = true)

from **A.example.com** -> **B.example.com/file.js**  (works with correct Headers)
When I try the same request from another domain : 
**C.dev.example.com** -> **B.example.com/file.js** // (it fails)

However for the second example when I look at the network logs in chrome 
my first request  **OPTIONS**:

it has the correct CORS response headers :

```
access-control-allow-headers: access-control-allow-headers
access-control-allow-methods: GET
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-max-age: 3000
content-length: 0
date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 14:38:36 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
via: 1.1 f19281f08e79aa6c6634266c50732dd5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: S2aMKSsJspB9p2RVxLMNh49iQ3Rc0Uims-EEIcjbxC42_OpqJpoUXQ==
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

However the **GET** Request (right after the OPTIONS) :

```
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 817
content-type: application/javascript
date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 14:19:46 GMT
etag: "5b85d498318db8095a776fdcae57c624"
last-modified: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 14:19:20 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
via: 1.1 f19281f08e79aa6c6634266c50732dd5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: C0xswS08mXDHkagm3phQT59wjclwEX9ZZHXr57OpZVMHzkf432H7dg==
x-cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
```

My TTL on the Cloudfront is 5 seconds (It has to be aggressive for my use case)
I'm using the **h2** protocol instead of the **http/1.1**

Comment: Did you follow these steps?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html

Comment: @Hackerman : I read all the documentation, my problem (apparently) for the first request the browser is not sending the 'Origin' header, so I get the response without CORS headers. After that it seems that the response is cached without these headers... When I wipe the cloudfront cache, and I do the request as it's supposed to be (C.dev -> file) I have the right headers.

Comment: Can you also add both, the `Request` and `Response` headers, for each call?

Comment: @Hackerman check this too : https://serverfault.com/questions/856904/chrome-s3-cloudfront-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-on-initial-xhr-req/856948#856948

Answer (score 2):

My problem is due to a known issue related to the fact that CloudFront doesn't send the 'Vary: Origin' header in the response, hence the response is cached by the browser that triggers the errors.

more details here : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=156134
and more details here too : https://serverfault.com/questions/856904/chrome-s3-cloudfront-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-on-initial-xhr-req/856948#856948

Comment: Technically, the issue is that S3 doesn't return the `Vary: Origin` header when the request is a non-CORS request.  CloudFront returns (and caches) what S3 provides, and the browser caches it, too, leaving the browser to incorrectly conclude that the cached response can be reused.  Note that your `date` headers suggest that the browser is reusing a response to a `GET` request that it made *before* the `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks ! can you mark this as a duplicate for the question in serverfault ?

Comment: I would, but questions posted on one SE site can't be marked as duplicates of questions on a different SE site.