# Amazon S3 weird CORS behaviour: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am storing images on amazon S3.

I use this CORS configuration for my bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.monteurzimmer-1a.de</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And I also have bucket rules:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue is:

My images are generally all visible without any issues, the error appeared after I added a script to rotate images based on their EXIF data.

Now if you visit the page (the one where images are rotated) for the FIRST time, you can still see the images, but the rotation is not applied AND I see the error in the console for each image: `... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

BUT if you reload the page once, than the error is gone and the rotation is applied. You can reproduce the issue by using incognito mode.

Visit [this page](https://www.monteurzimmer-1a.de/unterkunft-17-ferienwohnung%20erich%20und%20sabine%20wagner) in incognito mode. Images will be seen but rotation will be wrong, the error appears in the console. Hit F5 and the error is gone, rotation is applied.

I assume is has something to do with caching, but the rotation script is not on S3.

This is how I apply the rotation:

```
<img class="display-none" id="room_image_{{ loop.index }}"
onload="rotate_image(this)" alt="Zimmer Bild" 
src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/userimages/{{ image.path }}">
```

Here is the JS part:

```
function adjust_to_container($img, deg) {
    //console.log($img);
    //var parentHeight = $img.parent().height();
    var parentHeight = $img.parentElement.clientHeight;

    //console.log(parentHeight);
    if (deg == 90 || deg == 270) {
        $img.style.maxWidth = parentHeight + "px";
        //$img.css("max-width", parentHeight + "px");
    }
}

function rotate_image($img) {
    EXIF.getData($img, function() {
        console.log('Exif=', EXIF.getTag($img, "Orientation"));

        switch(parseInt(EXIF.getTag($img, "Orientation"))) {
            case 2:
                //$img.addClass('flip'); 
                $img.classList.add("flip");
                adjust_to_container(this, 180);
                break;
            case 3:
                //$img.addClass('rotate-180');
                $img.classList.add("rotate-180");
                adjust_to_container(this, 180);
                break;
            case 4:
                //$img.addClass('flip-and-rotate-180'); 
                $img.classList.add("flip-and-rotate-180");
                adjust_to_container(this, 180);
                break;
            case 5:
                //$img.addClass('flip-and-rotate-270'); 
                $img.classList.add("flip-and-rotate-270");
                adjust_to_container(this, 270);
                break;
            case 6:
                //$img.addClass('rotate-90'); 
                $img.classList.add("rotate-90");
                adjust_to_container(this, 90);
                break;
            case 7:
                //$img.addClass('flip-and-rotate-90'); 
                $img.classList.add("flip-and-rotate-90");
                adjust_to_container(this, 90);
                break;
            case 8:
                //$img.addClass('rotate-270'); 
                $img.classList.add("rotate-270");
                adjust_to_container(this, 270);
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

The `exif.js` and this script are loaded in the HTML `<HEAD>` because they must be there before the images are loaded.

Any ideas why this triggers a CORS problem?

**EDIT**

I assume is has something to do with EXIF.js. It uses `XMLHttpRequest` to process the images. Here is the [exit.js I use](https://pastebin.com/QfZ0DCsk):

**EDIT**

It seems this issue happens only on chrome browsers, which means the CORS configuration is ok?

Comment: you realize you are linking to a locahost site?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for telling me. I am testing right now on localhost and the live site. I corrected it.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: In case it works (after reloading the page) the code is 200. But on first try they dont even show up in the network tab. I have no clue how this is possible, because they are there. Only the rotation is missing.

Comment: I edited the question. I have an idea what it could be.

Comment: Can you add the OPTIONS method to the allowed methods?

Comment: OPTIONS is unsupported in S3. I get an error if I try to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `crossorigin="anonymous"` on the image tag and it seems the error is gone.

```
<img class="display-none" id="room_image_{{ loop.index }}"
onload="rotate_image(this)" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="Zimmer Bild" 
src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/userimages/{{ image.path }}">
```

A small explanation can be found in the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898035/html-crossorigin-attribute-for-img-tag).

Comment: S3 does not properly set the `Vary: origin` response header that Chrome expects, when CORS is enabled for the bucket but the request does not contain an `Origin` header -- which it won't when the image is fetched from an `<img>` tag -- so Chrome doesn't go back to verify whether the bucket will allow your origin to fetch objects in a CORS context -- it assumes the cached copy (which lacks `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) is the only variant that the origin would provide.  I believe your workaround bypasses the bug in S3 by changing the *original* request.  https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495021/response-from-cloudfront-from-s3-origin-keeps-changing-cors-headers